# SQL Server query to get top 10 products shipped, avg, mtd & ytd

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

For an inventory report, I need to generate output for the top 10 selling products

```
 product     description   in-stock   MTD     YTD     Avg
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
P1 (altp1)  product X     100         30     1000    33
P2 (altp2)  product Y      10          0      100     9
```

Product related tables:

- products (sku, description, ...)
- products_details (sku, altsku, ...)

Orders related tables:

- orders (id, shipped_date, ...)
- order_details (id, order_id, product_id, shipped_qty, ....)

Warehouse inventory

- inventory (id, [warehouse_id, product_id, qty, ...)

I tried to do SQL with joins and subqueries but the results took about 7 minutes to process

```
SELECT TOP 10
    p.sku
    ,p1.alt_sku
    ,p.description
    ,wh.qty
    ,SUM(od.shipped_qty) as YTD
    ,SUM(od.shipped_qty) as MTD
    ,AVG(od.shipped_qty) as AvgSales -- how do I get avg of last six months?
FROM product as p
INNER JOIN product_details as p1 ON p.sku = p1.sku
LEFT JOIN inventory as wh on wh.sku = p.sku
LEFT JOIN order_details as od on od.sku= p.sku
LEFT JOIN orders as o on o.order_id = od.order_id
WHERE o.shipped_date >= @YearStart
GROUP BY p.sku, p1.alt_sku, p.description, o.shipped_date, wh.qty, od.shipped_qty
ORDER by MTD DESC
```

I tried to use CTE which speeded up the query very much. But the result came up with duplicate skus and double entries

```
WITH CTE_Summary(product_id, yy, mm, shipped) as (
    SELECT 
        orders.product_id, yy, mm, SUM(orders.shipped_qty) as shipped
    FROM (
        select o.id
            , od.product_id
            , SUM(od.shipped_qty) shipped_qty
            , year(o.shipped_date) yy
            , month(o.shipped_date) mm
        from orders o
        LEFT JOIN order_details od on od.order_id = o.id
        GROUP BY o.id, od.product_id, year(o.shipped_date), month(o.shipped_date)   
    ) AS orders
    WHERE orders.yy >= YEAR(GetDate())
    GROUP BY orders.product_id, orders.yy, orders.mm
) 
SELECT  sku.sku, sku.description, sku.alt_sku, sku.instock, summ.avgshipped, summ.YTD, summ.MTD, sku.sku, sku.DESCR, sku.ALTSKU, sku.DESCR, sku.instock  
FROM (SELECT top 10 product_id
    , AVG(shipped) as avgshipped
    , SUM(shipped) as YTD
    , SUM(CASE WHEN mm = MONTH(GetDate()) THEN shipped ELSE 0 END) as mtd 
from CTE_Summary GROUP BY product_id order by mtd desc, ytd desc) summ
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT p1.sku, p1.description, p2.alt_sku, wh.qty as instock FROM products p1 
        LEFT JOIN product_details p2 ON p2.product_id = p1.id
        LEFT JOIN inventory wh on wh.product_id = p1.id
) sku ON sku.product_id = summ.product_id
```

However this returns multiple rows for each product (something like this)

```
 product     description   in-stock   MTD     YTD     Avg
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
P1 (altp1)  product X     100         30     1000    33
P1 (altp1)  product X     100         30     1000    33
P2 (altp2)  product Y      10          0      100     9
P2 (altp2)  product Y      10          0      100     9
P2 (altp2)  product Y      10          0      100     9
P3 (altp3)  product Z      30          0       20     1
...
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: A simple solution to your CTE duplication could be changing `SELECT sku.sku, sku.description...` to `SELECT DISTINCT sku.sku, sku.description...`

Comment: Talking about the first Query, I can see that you are using Left Join, and this is the main reason for the slow performance. I can see that you have YTD is equal to MTD (according to query but not to results you wrote). I would suggest: 1. be sure that your first query provides the right results (regardless of the time). 2. If you still face slow performance, disable some columns and joins and check which one is the reason. In Your Straightforward Query and Tables I do not think the CTE is changing the performance.

Comment: Try to convert the LEFT to INNER JOINS

Comment: TOP 10 also another reason to slow as it is SORTING the final result then take the TOP 10

Comment: I would recommend that your query is ```FROM order_details`````, and then join to other tables. The start point should not be the Products table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reworked the query and this is how it looks like. It loads up in 3 sec!

```
declare @ReportDate as date = GETDATE();
declare @YearStart as date = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@ReportDate), 1, 1);
declare @MonthStart as date = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@ReportDate), MONTH(@ReportDate), 1);
declare @Last6Months as date = DATEADD(mm, -6, @ReportDate)

WITH CTE_Summary (product_id, shipdate, shipped) AS (
    SELECT product_id, orders.shipped_date, order_details.shipped_qty FROM order_details 
        LEFT JOIN orders ON orders.order_id = order_details.order_id 
        WHERE orders.shipped_date BETWEEN IIF(@YearStart > @Last6Months, @Last6Months, @YearStart) AND @ReportDate
            AND orders.shipdate IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT TOP 10
        o.product_id 
        , ytd = (SELECT SUM(shipped) FROM CTE_Summary y where y.sku = o.sku AND y.shipdate >= @YearStart)
        , mtd = (SELECT SUM(shipped) FROM CTE_Summary m where m.sku = o.sku AND m.shipdate >= @MonthStart)
        , [avg] = (SELECT AVG(shipped) FROM CTE_Summary a where a.sku = o.sku AND a.shipdate>= @Last6Months)
        , stock = (SELECT qty FROM inventory wh where wh.sku = o.sku)
FROM CTE_Summary o
GROUP BY o.sku
order by ytd desc
```

Answer (score 1):

The top 10 product information is in the order_details table but you need to have the orders table to filter against the orders.shipped_date.
You need product table to get the product related information and the inventory table to know the current stock.

So I would start with order and order_details table inner joined because no use of the orders with null in the order_details table.

Every order details has the product sku so it should be inner joined with product'
Finally I'm considering all the products are inventory items and when we are finding for top selling products those must recorded in the inventory so inventory will be also inner joined.

Not sure why you are using product details in the query.
Though you have selected the alt_sku in the query but it's not in your result set.

If you no need this alt_sku and the top selling products by month the query would look like following.

```
DECLARE @FirstDayOfYear AS DATETIME = DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), 0);
DECLARE @CurrentMonth AS INTEGER = MONTH(GetDate());

SELECT TOP 10
    p.sku                   as product
    ,p.description          as [description]
    ,SUM(wh.qty)            as [in-stock]
    ,SUM(od.shipped_qty)    as YTD
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(o.shipped_date) = @CurrentMonth THEN od.shipped_qty ELSE 0 END)    as MTD
    ,AVG(od.shipped_qty)    as [Avg] 
FROM 
    orders as o
    INNER JOIN order_details    as od   on o.order_id = od.order_id
    INNER JOIN product          as p    on od.sku= p.sku
    INNER JOIN inventory        as wh   on wh.sku = p.sku
WHERE o.shipped_date >= @FirstDayOfYear
GROUP BY p.sku, p.description
ORDER by MTD DESC
```

Comment: the problem with this approach is that it takes 7+ minutes to retrieve results. thats why I was doing CTE and processing it

Comment: Hi @sabkaraja, referencing the comments I did on your post, I would recommend you start with this answer as it takes the Orders as a start point (I would suggest OrderDetails as a start point) and it works using INNER JOINS rather than LEFT JOINS.

Comment: hi @sabkaraja did you try this query? what was the execution time?

Comment: it took 7.5 minutes. I had gone this route first. But looking at the time consumed, I was reworking the query. Is PARTITION  OVER a better way to deal with this?

Comment: Is there proper indexing specially on the fields used in the joining?

Comment: @sabkaraja can you try with the edited where clause?